$\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry of surface inherited by embedded graph
Let $K$ be a graph with a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry. That is, there is an automorphism $\alpha:V(K)\mapsto V(K)$ such that $\alpha(\alpha(v))=v$ for all $v\in V(K)$. Suppose $K$ has genus $g$, and consider a drawing of $K$ on a compact orientable surface with genus $g$, which we call $S_g$. Such a surface also has a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry, though it will not be unique.
My question is as follows: is it always possible to draw $K$ on $S_g$ such that there is some continuous non-trivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map $z: S_g\rightarrow S_g$ such that $z(z(t))=t$ for all $t\in S_g$ and the restriction of $z$ to $V(K)$ is an automorphism of $K$?
If it helps, assume that all $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetries of $K$ have no fixed point. That is, for any automorphism $\alpha:V(K)\rightarrow V(K)$ with $\alpha(\alpha(v))=v$, it holds that $\alpha(v)\neq v$ for all $v\in V(K)$.

The usual definition of the $n$-torus is the product of $n$ circles. Is it what you mean? Or do you mean the unique orientable compact surface of genus $n$ (which a topologist would never call an $n$-torus)?

An easy result is that if $K$ admits an order 2 symmetry $\tau$, there exists an embedding of $K$ in a compact orientable surface $S$ such that $\tau$ extends to an order 2 symmetry of $S$. I do not know if this can be done for $S$ whose genus is the genus of $K$. This is probably false already for $K=K_5$.

Yeah I mean the unique compact orientable surface of genus $n$.

How would you prove your last statement?

Please revise your question accordingly.

Fixed it accordingly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is an answer to some form of your question. It requires some basic understand of geometric and algebraic topology, so you might have hard time reading it. Hopefully, it will be useful for somebody.
Let $G$ be a graph embedded in an oriented surface $S$. Then for every vertex $v\in V(G)$ the embedding $G\to S$ and orientation of $S$ define a cyclic order on the set $E_v$ of half-edges of $G$ emanating from $v$. Suppose that $f: S\to S$ is a homeomorphism preserving $G$. Then for every vertex $v\in V(G)$ and $w=f(v)\in V(G)$, the map $f$ induces a map $E_v\to E_w$ and this map either preserves or reverses the cyclic orders (preserves if and only if $f: S\to S$ is orientation-preserving).
Note that if $A$ is a finite set equipped with a cyclic order and $\phi: A\to A$ is a bijection preserving or reversing this order, then $\phi$ cannot have more than two fixed points, unless $\phi$ is the identity map. Now, let $D$ be the $D_5$-graph (see the picture).

This graph has a unique nontrivial involution $\sigma$; this involution fixes the vertices $1, 2, 3$ and swaps the vertices $4$ and $5$. Let $G$ be the graph which is the cone over $D$, i.e. $V(G)=\{1,...,6\}$, $G$ contains $D$ as the subgraph with the vertices $\{1,...,5\}$ and the edge-set of $G$ consists of the edges of $D$ and all the edges $[k, 6], k=1,...,5$. Then $G$ has a unique involution $\tau$: This involution fixes the vertex $6$ and acts as $\sigma$ on the subgraph $D$. Therefore:
Lemma 1. There does not exist an embedding of $G$ to an oriented surface $S$ such that $S$ admits a nontrivial involution preserving the image of $G$ in $S$.
On the other hand:
Lemma 2. Suppose that $G$ is any graph and $\phi: G\to G$ is an involution of $G$ not fixing any vertices. Then there are cyclic orderings of sets $E_v, v\in V(G)$, such that all induced maps $\phi_v: E_v\to E_{\phi(v)}$  the cyclic orders.
Proof. Suppose that $v, w$ are (distinct) vertices of $G$ such that $\phi(v)=w$ (and, thus, $\phi(w)=v$ since $\phi$ is an involution).
Then take an arbitrary cyclic order $o_v$ on $E_v$ and give $E_w$ the cyclic order $o_w$
which is the image of $o_v$ under $\phi_v$. Then, clearly
$$
\phi_v: (E_v,o_v)\to (E_w, o_w), \phi_w:  (E_w,o_w)\to (E_v, o_v)
$$
both preserve the cyclic orders. We repeat this for all pairs of distinct vertices of $G$ which are swapped by $\phi$. qed
Theorem. Suppose that $G$ is a finite graph,
$$\phi: G\to G$$
is an involution without fixed vertices. Then there exists
an embedding of $G$ in a compact oriented surface $S$ such that $\phi$ extends to a (continuous) involution of $S$. Moreover,
if $G$ is connected, so is $S$, and $S$ has genus $1-\chi(G)$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic.
Proof. Using Lemma 2, we we define cyclic orders $o_v$ on the sets $E_v, v\in V(G)$, such that for every $v\in V(G)$ the induced map
$\phi_v$ preserves the cyclic orders. Using these cyclic order one defines a ribbon graph stricture on $G$, which I explain below. Identify each vertex $v\in V(G)$ with a point $p_v$ in the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Take a unit disk $D_v\subset \mathbb R^2$ centered at $p_v$. Subdivide the boundary circle of $D_v$ into arcs $\alpha_i, i=1,...,d_v$ of equal length, where $d_v$ is the degree of $v$ listed clockwise so that when we have a bijection between the half-edges in $E_v$ and the arcs $\alpha_i$ preserving the cyclic order.  Now, suppose that $e$ is an edge in $G$ connecting vertices $v, w$ (it's possible that $v=w$). The half-edges of $e$ correspond to the boundary arcs $\alpha_i, \beta_j$ in the boundary circles of $D_v, D_w$ respectively. Next, take the rectangle $R_e:=e\times [0,1]$ and glue it to the disks $D_v, D_w$ so that $e\times \{0\}$ is glued to the arc $\alpha_i$ and $e\times \{1\}$ is glued to the arc $\beta_j$. This gluing is not unique, we choose one such that after the gluing is done, the orientations of $D_v, D_w$ extend over to the rectangle $R_e=e\times [0,1]$ to matching orientations. We extend the segment $\tilde{e}:=e\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}\subset R_e$ to a segment $\hat{e}\subset D_v\cup R_e\cup D_w$ by connecting the end-points of $\tilde{e}$ to the centers $p_v, p_w$ by radial line segments in $D_v, D_w$ respectively. We proceed in this fashion for all edges of $G$. The result is a compact oriented surface with boundary $R$ built out of the disks $D_v$ and the rectangles $R_e$. This surface is connected if and only if $G$ is connected. Furthermore, $G$ is embedded in $F$ so that $R$ deformation retracts to the image of $G$: We map each vertex $v\in V(G)$ to the center $p_v$. We map each edge $e$ to the segment $\hat{e}\subset R$. This gives us the embedding. Since $G$ is homotopy-equivalent to $R$, we have
$$
\chi(R)=\chi(G),
$$
where $\chi$ stands for the Euler characteristic. Let $S$ denote the double of $R$ across its boundary: We glue two copies
of $R$ along their respective boundaries via the identity map. Then $S$ is compact, oriented and has empty boundary. Moreover,
$\chi(S)=2\chi(R)=2\chi(G)$. If $G$ is connected, then and $g$ is its genus  of $S$, then
$$
2-2g= 2\chi(G), g= 1-\chi(G). 
$$
We next deal with the involution $\phi$ of $G$. We extend $\phi$ to a (continuous) involution of $S$ in two steps. The first step is to extend $\phi$ to an involution of the surface $R$. Whenever $\phi(v)=w$, we let $f_v: D_v\to D_w$ be the unique rigid motion sending $p_v$ to $p_w$ and matching the boundary arcs $\alpha_i$ in $\partial D_v$ to the corresponding (under $\phi_v$) boundary arcs $\beta_i$ in $\partial D_w$. Then $f_w\circ f_v$ is the identity map. We extend these maps to homeomorphisms $f_e: R_e\to R_{e'}$ ($e'=f(e)$) in such a way that the segment $\tilde{e}$ maps to $\tilde{e'}$ and  $f_{e'}\circ f_e=id$. Combining the maps $f_v, f_e$ we obtain an involution $f: R\to R$ extending $\phi$. Lastly, we extend the involution $f$ to an involution $\Phi: S\to S$ by using a copy of
$f$ on the second copy of the surface $R$. qed
I doubt that in this theorem one can find a surface $S$ whose genus is the genus of $G$, but I do not have any examples.

In the proof of Theorem 2, what is the importance of $D_v, D_w$ and $R_e$ having matching orientation? Is this to guarantee that the resulting surface $S$ is orientable?
If we remove the assumption that the surface we are embedding $G$ in needs to be orientable, can we then embed $G$ in a compact surface $S'$ where any involution with no fixed point extends to a continuous involution of $S'$ and $S'$ has same genus as $G$?
I'd imagine this can be done by `twisting' some of the rectangles $R_e$ before gluing them to the discs.

@mirewine: Yes, it is to ensure orientability. Even if you do not make this assumption, my construction will hardly ever give you the minimal genus. (For instance, if $G$ is the complete graph on three vertices, my construction will give you the torus or the Klein bottle instead of the sphere.)
